# fontawesome onclick icon change angular using material table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

I want to fill favorite icon when it's empty. While click on the favorite icon i have to display solid favorite icon.

I tried like below code

```
    <span class="icon iconVisibile" (click)="isClicked()">
            <i class="fa-star"[ngClass]="isSelectedFav ? 'fas' : 'far'"></i>
    </span>
```

ts

```
   public isSelected:boolean = false;
   isClicked(){
     this.isSelected = true;
     console.log(this.isSelected);
   }
```

with above code that is not working please let me know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: What is isSelectedFav ?

Comment: @pc_coder i have modified the console

Comment: @pc_coder Yes i can able to see my icon but when i click the favorite icon i want to make it active that is not happening

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-font-awesome-starter-mwr3uo) Your problem seems that font awesome return i element tag to svg. That is why you can't change it. you should close `autoReplaceSvg` property in font awesome

put below ones in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: false }
</script>
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

component.ts

```
public isSelected:boolean = false;
isClicked(){
   this.isSelected = true;
}
```

html

```
<span class="icon iconVisibile" (click)="isClicked()">
     <i class="fa-star"[ngClass]="isSelected ? 'fas' : 'far'"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: i was able to see my icon when i mouse over in the mat row i can able to see  but when i click the icon it should active (fill the icon) that is not happening

Comment: Updated answer your problem is that font awesome returnicon element to svg thats why you cant change. I added on mor script to prevent it @Mahadevan